# sharePoint 2010 - Exchanger server 2010 - integration , BCS

Tags: .net, exchange

I need to access account information programmatically from a MS Exchange 2010 server, then import them back into SharePoint 2010.

Is this feasible, if so how can it be done?
any help and resources appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can do it. I assume you will need to run the program on SP server to access EX info on EX server. You will need to install Exchange Management Shell on SP server (run Ex install, you can install the EMS only), so that you can remote access all Ex servers.

Then use C# to run the cmdlet to get whatever info you want. Then use C# & cmdlet to import data to SP.

Here is an example of using C# for EMS:
http://blog.abstractinvoke.com/2011/11/using-the-exchange-management-shell-from-c/